# React-Native- Detox - How to change DatePicker value in Android

Tags: react-native, detox

For iOS we have [setColumnToValue](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#setcolumntovaluecolumn-value--ios-only) for dynamically selecting value in Picker. I searched a lot in google but couldn't find any solution for Android.

If anyone has faced the same issue and having some workaround then please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think anyone has implemented it. PRs are welcome.